# Automation Studio next run set less hour than starting time

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, automation, test-automation, schedule

I scehduled Automation that activte today 3pm
And when I complete this set and check it,
in automation, the next run is today 2pm.

Is it right? I want to fix it.
[image]

Comment: It looks like a UI bug! Have you raised this with support?